# How to make a div scroll when I scroll after certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a div, that is situated beneath a block of content but that once the page has been scrolled enough to contact its top boundary, becomes fixed in place and scrolls with the page. I know I've seen at least one example of this online but I cannot remember it for the life of me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964784/google-news-left-nav-css-trick-or-jquery-trick/3965179#3965179

Comment: do you want fixed footer kind of functionality , is so we can achive that by css also without writing javascript

Comment: I want a div that is at the middle of the screen, when I scroll down before the div is hidden I want it to stick to the top of the window and stay there. When I scroll back up to the top I want it to stick on its original place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/oqusa3/3)]**

```
var el  = $("#sticky");
var win = $(window);
var width  = el.width();
var height = el.height();
var win_height = $(window).height();

window.onscroll = function() {
  var offset = el.offset().top + height - win_height;
  if ( win.scrollTop() > offset ) {
    window.onscroll = function() { 
      el.css({
        width: width,
        position: "absolute",
        top: win.scrollTop() + win_height - height
      });
    };  
  }
};
```

If you don't need to support IE based browsers you can use:

```
position: "fixed"
bottom: 0
```

Comment: hmm, this answer doesn't do "I want a div that is at the middle of the screen, when I scroll down before the div is hidden I want it to stick to the top of the window and stay there. When I scroll back up to the top I want it to stick on its original place." to me.  I'd love to know how to get something like mashable's blog effect (see http://mashable.com/2011/10/25/windows-xp-it-will-not-die/ the share buttons on the left)

Comment: search for it, and if you don't it on SO post a question and I (or others) will answer.